# C# Tic Tac Toe game: How to disable already selected buttons?

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

**How to enable a button that is already pressed in Tic Tac Toe game? (c#)**

Hi,I am a coding beginner and I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game. I need a code that user cannot click a button that is already charged.

(For example, if the text of a button is already "X", you cannot change it to "O")

For now, I have an incomplete IF structure and I don't know what condition to put. I tried every possible thing that I know but it didn't work...

```cs
string Player = "X";

private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int turn = 0;

  Button currentButton = (Button) sender;
  currentButton.Text = Player;

  if ( /** if the button is already pressed **/ )
  {
    currentButton.Enabled = false;
  }
  else {
    if (Player == "O") {
      Player = "X";
    }
    else {
      Player = "O";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If text (Player) is "X" then you do not want to change it to "O". but your code is changing it to "O" When it is "X". (In case that is what you are talking)
Else part needs to be removed so it will be like below.

```
        if (Player == "O")
        { 
            Player = "X";
        }
```

Comment: Oops, that is another mistake I made. Thank you for the feedback! But I wonder what should I put at the top of the IF condition to disable a button that is already pressed with "X"/"O"

Answer (score 0):

Try just disabling the button:

```cs
currentButton.Text = Player;
currentButton.Enabled = false;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check it, if button is clickable it means it was enabled. Which means it was first time it was clicked. You just need to disable it with no condition. Like:

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int turn = 0;
            
            Button currentButton = (Button)sender;
            currentButton.Text = Player;
            currentButton.Enabled = false;

            if (Player == "O")
            { 
                Player = "X";
            }
            else
            {
                Player = "O";
            }

        }
```